# Uploading product images

Tags: upload

Im creating a site where a user can upload multiple(multiselect) product images at once.

My question is what would be the the "right" way if the user uploads images that have the same name as the ones that are already in the destination folder..
Should I just override the existing one´s with the new images or just add the ones that have not the same name and skip the existing ones.. perhaps prompt the user about it? Im leaning towards overriding the existing one´s..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the best experience is to **ask before doing the update**, maybe you did a change to your file and the versioning not reflected on the file name, so the best case is to prompt the user in order to choose either overwrite the existing one or keep another version of the same file.

Even in this case there are a number of approaches check below:

1- **Option1** The system prompts the user and asks the permission to either Overwrite or keep both versions.

2- **Option2** as **Google** using, is to finish upload and then give the user the decision either keep both or remove the old version.

Hope this can help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ask, why wouldn't you?

I'm not being flippant, or maybe a little bit, but what are the ramifications of each scenario? Given that images are personal - I'm leaning towards asking - outside of any other information.

Comment: If I would not override the existing ones, then the user would most likely be suprised to see that his new images are not present after the upload.. That will cause problems and uncertainty for the user. Im coding this as I write "here" this comment and after giving the whole scenario a greater thought I think I need to prompt the user that his/hers images will be overrwritten if they want to. Wouldn you agree?

Comment: The other scenario would be that I have to create the "new" image and save it the same place with a new name(Copy)..

Answer (score 1):

Ask! Just like in your OS. It's extra complexity, sure, but it's what users are used to and is probably the most surefire way to avoid a terrible experience when something gets overwritten.